# How can i add a default message with php mail function?

Tags: php, html, email

I have created an html form that after the user clicks "send" redirects to mail.php which contains php mail function that works and sends the desired message.
Is there any way to also add a default message for example "This was sent from the website" to the email?

Form from index.html

```
    <form method="post" action="mail.php">
            <div class="form-style">
               <h1 class="formh1">Full Name</h1>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full name" required>
                <h1 class="formh1">Email address</h1>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                <h1 class="formh1">Message</h1>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Give us your thought" required></textarea>
            <div class="button-form">
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Mail.php

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
  $from = 'myemail'; // Use your own email address
  $subject = 'The following message was sent from the website';
  $message = 'Fullname: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= 'Email address: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
  $name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"name",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
  $email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"email",FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
  $details = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"message",FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
  $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  header('Location: index.html');

  if ($email) {
     $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $email";
  }
  $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
  $success = mail($from, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
```

?>

Comment: You can add whatever you want to the email's body (`$message`) - it's just a string

Comment: Um... `$message .= 'This e-mail was sent from the website';`? *shrug*

Comment: well, i used this $message .= 'Hello'; but doesn't show it in the email

Answer (score 1):

Just add the default email your would like to send to the `$message` variable:

```
$message = 'This is my default message lalalalalal'
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but for some reason if i place $message = 'This is my default message lalalalalal'; before $message = 'Fullname: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n"; it won't show up .

Comment: Of course not, since you reassign `$message` as a string rather than `$message .=` which concatenates.

Comment: anyway to do it with conflicting the codes? add new variable?

Answer (score 1):

You just amend before, or after... wherever you want to inject that content.

When you use **$var .= "something added!";** - You're appending/concatenating additional text in this case.

When you use **$var = "something added!";** - w/o The .= you've reset the variable to the new string.

Think of .= being the same as **$message = $message . "String being added to message"**

```
$from = 'myemail'; // Use your own email address
$subject = 'The following message was sent from the website';
#EXAMPLE HERE - Also note I added htmlspecialchars
#These will convert any misc. characters to html readable content.
#Test with it, see if it fits. Just don't add it to $email = trim...
$message = "Your friend " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) . " has sent you a message from www.mywebsite.com"\r\n\r\n;
$message .= 'Fullname: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'Email address: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
$name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"name",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"email",FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
$details = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"message",FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```